# Getting an java.net.SocketTimeoutException while sending/receiving UDP-DatagramPacket

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, datagram

I'm creating a DatagramPacket that I'm trying to send to my "localhost" through a better oriented and reliable UDP-Protocol (manually created: I'm adding manually a header with a Checksum, Sequence-Number and the Length of the data) and then wait for an Acknowlegment from Server.

At the beginnig was everything okay, I sent many files, ones that are just 1-packet length (1000Bytes), other ones with 20 packets of each 1000 Bytes and I had no problem, server responded with the right ACKs (Acknowledgments), and everything was okay!
But somehow, after 5min, my program is not sending the files anymore, it sends just one packet and then stops with an exception...

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketReceiveOrPeekData(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(Unknown Source)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(Unknown Source)
at blatt7.FileSender.sendFile(FileSender.java:100)
at blatt7.FileSender.main(FileSender.java:184)"
```

Sorry the code is too long, but if someone could help, it would be REALLY good!!
Thankyou!
here is my Client-Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;

public class FileSender {

DatagramSocket sock = null;
CRC32 checksumRechner = new CRC32();
private byte[] readLength;
private byte[] seqNrArray;
private byte[] checksumArray;
private String dateiPfad;
private String zielRechner;
private InetAddress host;
private File datei;
private int seqNr = 1;
FileInputStream fis;
int counter = 0;
byte[] daten = new byte[1000];
byte[] header = new byte[16];
byte[] packet;
byte[] ack_buffer = new byte[4];
int port = 7777;
DatagramPacket dp;
DatagramPacket ack_dp = new DatagramPacket(ack_buffer, ack_buffer.length);
private long receivedSeqNr = 0;
private int readLen;

public FileSender(String zielRechner, String dateiPfad) throws IOException {
    this.setZielRechner(zielRechner);
    this.setDateiPfad(dateiPfad);
    setHost(InetAddress.getByName(zielRechner));
    setDatei(new File(dateiPfad));
    fis = new FileInputStream(datei);
}

public void sendFile() throws IOException {
    while((readLen = fis.read(daten)) != -1) {
        if (getSeqNr() == 1)
            seqNr = 0;
        else
            seqNr = 1;

        readLength = intToBytes(readLen);

        for (int i = 0; i < readLength.length; i++) {
            header[8+i] = readLength[i];
        }

        seqNrArray = intToBytes(getSeqNr());

        for (int i = 0; i <seqNrArray.length; i++) {
            header[12+i] = seqNrArray[i];
        }

        packet = new byte[header.length + daten.length];

        //wir fügen Daten und Header ins Packet zusammen.
        int j=0; 
        for (int i=0; i<packet.length; i++) {
            if (i < header.length) 
                packet[i] = header[i];
            else { 
                packet[i] = daten[j];
                j++;
            }
        }

        //wir rechnen die prüfsumme
        checksumRechner.reset();
        checksumRechner.update(packet,8,8+readLen);

        checksumArray = longToBytes(checksumRechner.getValue());

        //wir schreiben uns checksum in das packet
        for(int i=0; i < 8; i++) {
            packet[i] = checksumArray[i];
        }

        dp = new DatagramPacket(packet , packet.length , host , port);

        while (receivedSeqNr == seqNr) {
            try {
                sock = new DatagramSocket();
                sock.send(dp);
                sock.setSoTimeout(7000);
                counter++;
                System.out.println("Paket sent with seqNr: " + getSeqNr() + " und Length: " + getReadLen() + " - PAKET NR: " + counter);
                sock.receive(ack_dp);
                ack_buffer = ack_dp.getData();
                receivedSeqNr = bytesToLong(ack_buffer,0);
                System.out.println("got SeqNr, with receivedSeq-Nr: " + receivedSeqNr);
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e)
            { 
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    fis.close();
}   


public static byte[] longToBytes(long value) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    buffer.putLong(value);
    return buffer.array();
}

public static long bytesToLong(byte[] bytes, int index) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    buffer.put(bytes);
    buffer.flip();//need flip 
    return buffer.getLong(index);
}

public static byte[] intToBytes(int value) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    buffer.putInt(value);
    return buffer.array();
}

public static int bytesToInt(byte[] bytes, int index) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    buffer.put(bytes);
    buffer.flip();//need flip 
    return buffer.getInt(index);
}

public String getDateiPfad() {
    return dateiPfad;
}

public void setDateiPfad(String dateiPfad2) {
    this.dateiPfad = dateiPfad2;
}

public String getZielRechner() {
    return zielRechner;
}

public void setZielRechner(String zielRechner) {
    this.zielRechner = zielRechner;
}

public InetAddress getHost() {
    return host;
}

public void setHost(InetAddress host) {
    this.host = host;
}

public File getDatei() {
    return datei;
}

public void setDatei(File datei) {
    this.datei = datei;
}

public int getSeqNr() {
    return seqNr;
}

public int getReadLen() {
    return readLen;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException {

    FileSender sender = new FileSender("localhost", "C:/Users/Kb/Desktop/wifi pops.txt");
    sender.sendFile();

}

}
```

and my Server's-Code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
```

public class FileReceiver {

```
static byte[] buffer;
DatagramPacket incoming;
DatagramSocket serverSock = null;
CRC32 checksumRechner = new CRC32();
int dataLength;
long checksumReceiver;
long checksumSender;
int port = 7777;
int receivedSeqNr;

public FileReceiver() {
    buffer = new byte[1500];
    incoming = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
}

public void receive() {
    try
    {
        //1. Erstellung eines server sockets, parameter ist localportnummer
        serverSock = new DatagramSocket(port);
        serverSock.setSoTimeout(10000);

        //2. Warten für incoming data
        echo("Server socket created. Waiting for incoming data...");

        //kommunikationsloop
        while(true)
        {   
            serverSock.receive(incoming);

            byte[] dataLengthArray = new byte[4];
            for (int i=0; i <4; i++) {
                dataLengthArray[i] = buffer[i+8];
            }
            dataLength = FileSender.bytesToInt(dataLengthArray,0);

            checksumRechner.reset();
            checksumRechner.update(buffer, 8, dataLength+8);


            checksumReceiver = checksumRechner.getValue();

            byte[] receivedSeqNrArray = new byte[4];
            for (int i=0; i <4; i++) {
                receivedSeqNrArray[i] = buffer[i+12];
            }
            receivedSeqNr = FileSender.bytesToInt(receivedSeqNrArray,0);

            byte[] receivedChecksumArray = new byte[8];
            for (int i=0; i <8; i++) {
                receivedChecksumArray[i] = buffer[i];
            }
            long receivedChecksumNr = FileSender.bytesToLong(receivedChecksumArray,0);

            System.out.println("Paket received with checksum: " + receivedChecksumNr);
            System.out.println("Server-generated checksum: " + checksumReceiver);
            System.out.println("Paket got, with seqNr: " + receivedSeqNr + " und length: " + dataLength);
            if (checksumReceiver != receivedChecksumNr)  {
                sendACK(receivedSeqNr);
                System.out.println("Paket has errors! Must be sent again!");
            }
            else if(checksumReceiver == receivedChecksumNr && receivedSeqNr == 1) {
                sendACK(0);
                System.out.println("SeqNr sent --> SeqNr: 0");
            }
            else if (checksumReceiver == receivedChecksumNr && receivedSeqNr == 0) {
                sendACK(1);
                System.out.println("SeqNr sent --> SeqNr: 1");
            }


         }
     }
     catch(IOException e)
     {
         System.err.println("IOException " + e);
     }
 }


 //echo data ausgeben
public static void echo(String msg)
{
    System.out.println(msg);
}

public void sendACK(int seqNum) throws IOException {
    byte[] sendArray = FileSender.intToBytes(seqNum);
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendArray, sendArray.length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 7777);
    serverSock.send(sendPacket);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException {

    FileReceiver receiver = new FileReceiver();
    receiver.receive();

}

}
```

Comment: perhaps you are not dealing with packet loss correctly. In TCP SocketTimeoutException is recoverable, it just warns you have been waiting a while and you can try again after taking some action.  BTW How will this be better than reliable TCP? ;)

Comment: As @PeterLawrey said, this is why we invented TCP :)

Comment: As an exercise, you can try to write your own reliable UDP but even commercial grade UDP transports have problems with negative ack storms and often need to have their own independent networks as they are very sensitive to network loads.

Comment: it's a netwoking-homework that's why :-) We should make UDP more "reliable"..
so.. don't you have an idea about what I should do? Its annoing because it was working fine!!! should be just a little thing :/ have you tried to execute the code to see where is the problem? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I'm sending and receiving DatagramPackets, so yes, it can be a SocketTimeoutException by receiving the packets..